# Roles, niveles o privilegios de usuario Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo una duda sobre los roles o privilegios de usuario en Codeigniter, tengo un pagina en la cual puedo cambiar el rol de cada usuario si es administrador o usuario limitado, lo que no puedo hacer es que al momento de iniciar sesión cargue su perfil si es administrador con mas privilegios y si es usuario limitado con menos, aqui tengo mis controladores
Controller Login (Funcion para iniciar sesión)

```
    // Verificar usuario en base de datos
public function iniciar_sesion(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nom_usuario', 'nom_usuario', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass_usuario', 'pass_usuario', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
    $nom_usuario = $this->input->post('nom_usuario');
    $pass_usuario = $this->input->post('pass_usuario');
    $result = $this->Login_model->logearse($nom_usuario, $pass_usuario);
    if($result){
            $sess_array = array();
            foreach($result as $row){
        $sess_array = array(
               'nom_usuario' => $row->nom_usuario,
               'pass_usuario' => $row->pass_usuario,
                     'tipo_usuario' => $row->tipo_usuario
              );
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
        }else{
            echo "error";
        }

}
```

El modelo del controlador

```
function logearse($nom_usuario, $pass_usuario){
$this -> db -> select('nom_usuario, pass_usuario');
$this -> db -> from('usuarios');
$this -> db -> where('nom_usuario', $nom_usuario);
$this -> db -> where('pass_usuario', $pass_usuario);
$this -> db -> limit(1);

$query = $this -> db -> get();

if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
{
return $query->result();
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

}

El controlador del panel o de la pagina a mostrar si esta logueado

```
  //Cargar la vista Panel
public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $this->load->view('header.php');
        $this->load->view('panel');
        $this->load->view('footer.php');
}
else
{
  //Si no ha iniciado sesion redirecionar a login
  redirect('login');

}
}
```

Que en el controlador del panel pudiera ir un if para redireccionar a su debido perfil pero no se como insertarlo, ¿Alguna idea? gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando trabajo con las sesiones de los diferentes tipos de usuario lo programo en el controlador de la siguiente manera.
El codigo esta comentado para que te vayas guiando, espero y te sirva.

```
public function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();

    //revisamos si NO existen las sesiones (se toman los datos necesarios para hacer la comparacion)
    if (!$this->session->userdata("id_usuario") && 
        !$this->session->userdata("username") && 
        !$this->session->userdata("tipo_usuario") &&
        !$this->session->userdata("login_activo")) 
    {
        //Mensaje de error
        $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Acceso Restringido");
        redirect(base_url()."index.php/login_control"); //ruta a la que queremis que nos redireccione
    } else if($this->session->userdata("tipo_usuario")==2){ //validamos las sesiones correctas del usuaario
        redirect(base_url()."index.php/login_control");
    }else if($this->session->userdata("tipo_usuario")==3){ //validamos las sesiones correctas del usuaario
        redirect(base_url()."index.php/login_control");
    }
    $this->load->model('sesion_model');
}//./constructor
```

Comment: Oye javier esta es la mejor manera de verificar los privilegios de usuario o que recomiendas?